# jQuery Validation not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate my form submission using jqueryvalidation.js .

when I am using this code this time validation works only firefox

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({

    if(success)
    {
        $("#addbusiness").submit();
    }
});
$( "#addbusiness" ).validate({
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        }
    }
});
```

If I use this code then validation not working all browser

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({


    if($("#addevent").valid())
{
    $("#addevent").submit();
}
});
$( "#addevent" ).validate({
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        }
    }
});
```

I want if my form not valid then form can't submit.

Comment: Please refer to the [SO Tag Wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for basic usage of the plugin and links to more information.

Answer (score 2):

This part of your code...

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    if (success) {
        $("#addbusiness").submit();
    }
});
```

The `.setDefaults()` method **can only accept an object literal** (comprised of `key:value` pairs of [options as per the author](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)).  You cannot put a JavaScript conditional in there without breaking the method and probably the whole plugin.  Even as a function, it wouldn't work anyway, since `success` is not defined as anything in this context.

> I want if my form not valid then form can't submit.

There would be no point to using the jQuery Validation plugin if it allowed the form to submit.  ***By default*, when properly configured, it will prevent submit until the form is valid**...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#addevent").validate({
        rules: {
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="addevent">
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/cLqh4j2v/**